# Core Data Error when segueing: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class

Tags: ios, core-data, initialization, nsmanagedobject

I have a view controller that segues to another view controller when a pin on the mapView is tapped. "Pin" is an NSManagedObject that gets populated with latitude and longitude before being sent to the second view controller (where a function populates it with actual images).

I am getting the error "CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Pin'" after my didSelect function is completed and before my performSegue function is called.

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Pin> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Pin>(entityName: "Pin")
}

@NSManaged public var latitude: Double
@NSManaged public var longitude: Double
@NSManaged public var images: NSSet?
```

This is the class:

```
convenience init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pin", in: context) {
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    } else {
        fatalError("Unable to find entity name")
    }
}
```

I have tried declaring pin as an optional and force declaring it with "!". None of these two options works. Based on what I've learned and read on many posts online I will need to initialize the pin variable using the designated initializer. This is my attempt at the top of the view controller class, but it's not working either.

```
var pin = Pin.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pin", in: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)!, insertInto: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)
```

Creating the pin:

```
    // Create the annotation
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let newCoordinate = self.mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom:self.mapView)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate


    pin = Pin(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude, context: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)
    let pinAnnotation = PinAnnotation(objectID: pin.objectID, title: nil, subtitle: nil, coordinate: annotation.coordinate)

    // Add the annotation
    mapView.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)
    CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
```

Selecting the pin in didSelect:

```
do {
        let pinAnnotation = view.annotation as! PinAnnotation
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Pin")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude == %@ AND longitude == %@", argumentArray: [pinAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, pinAnnotation.coordinate.longitude])
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let pins = try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Pin]
        pin = pins![0]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("failed to get pin by object id")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "collectionViewSegue", sender: self)
```

...and performing the segue:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "collectionViewSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
        print("CoreDataStack context in segue= \(CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)")
            controller.selectedPin = pin
            if let images = pin.images?.allObjects as? [Images] {
                controller.photos = images
            }
        print("PrepareForSegue pin properties are: \n latitude: \(pin.latitude) \n longitude: \(pin.longitude)")
        }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by making my variable declaration optional in the beginning of my class:

```
var selectedPin: Pin?
```

...and initializing differently within my long press gestureRecognizer function:

```
    @objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state != .began { return }
    print("Tap gesture recognized")

    // Create the annotation
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let newCoordinate = self.mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom:self.mapView)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate

    // Initialize NSManagedObject 'Pin' with properties
    selectedPin = Pin(context: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)
    selectedPin?.latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude
    selectedPin?.longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude

    if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
    let pinAnnotation = PinAnnotation(objectID: selectedPin.objectID, title: nil, subtitle: nil, coordinate: annotation.coordinate)

    // Add the annotation
    mapView.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)
    }

    CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
    print("This is what the ole save looks like: \(CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)")
}
```